# Facebook Graph API: Feed publishing showing up as link type instead of status?

Tags: c#, json, facebook

So I'm publishing to a Facebook Group's Feed in my app, using the Graph API.  It works fine, except facebook keeps treating the published info as a 'link' feed item type instead of 'status' like it does when I enter the same from facebook's site.

eg:

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/<id-of-group/feed?access_token=<access-token>";
string data = "message=hello";

webClient.UploadString(url, "POST", data);
```

Now when I pull the feed items, the json that is returned has "item":"link", with "link":"http://www.facebook.com", whereas I'd expect it to be "item":"status" and no or an empty "link" property.

Any ideas?

Comment: please explain more about your question. What you exactly want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was most likely a bug that has been fixed since then, the JSON works correctly now giving the correct type as

```
"type": "status",
```

For more information on posting to groups see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/#feed